# Alternatives to large IN clause in JDBC, how to use Table Value Parameters from Java?

Tags: java, spring, sql-server-2008, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using SQL Server 2008 RC2.

We often have to do a query similar to this:

```
select * from Site s where s.name in (:names)
```

Where `":names"` is a big `StringBuilder` of 1000 comma-separated 18-byte names. This takes a while to run; up to a minute on my local development machine. I know that many people have suggested the use of `Table Valued Parameters` (TVP) for this, such as the example below:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_TestSites] @siteNames SiteNameTableType readonly
as
begin
    select s.* from Site s
       inner join @siteNames d on d.name = s.name
end
```

But since the Microsoft JDBC Driver still doesn't support TVP (as far as I know), what is the best way to achieve this? Send one long String of comma separated values to a Stored Procedure and then split the string in the procedure and insert into a temp table? Example:

```
create type dbo.SiteNameTableType as table(
    name varchar(18) not null unique
)

create procedure sp_TestSites(
    @longStringOfNames varchar(max))
as
begin
    declare @siteNames SiteNameTableType

    insert into @siteNames
    select * from dbo.split(@longStringOfNames) -- assume I have a Split function

    select s.* from Site s
       inner join @siteNames d on d.name = s.name
end
```

Comment: How about sending data in as XML and deal with it as with XML in the SP?

Comment: Hm, that seems to work pretty well!

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I think we will go with this approach. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. Just a bit troublesome to have to generate the XML by oneself...

Comment: Yup, a bit prep is required, but the benefit is you can query and join to the data. Thanks, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can prepare the data as an XML string and pass it to the stored procedure. Inside the SP you can query that XML and join to the resultset as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass a CSV string to your SP, use a FUNCTION in the SP that converts the CSV string into a TVP and then use that?

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_TABLE_FROM_CSVSTRING] ( @CSVString VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS  @Result TABLE(ItemValue VARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @x XML 
    SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@CSVString,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)

    INSERT INTO @Result            
    SELECT t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS inVal
    FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)

    RETURN
END   
GO
```

I do not know if this is the fastest string splitter but I will check around a little.
Note: For possible better performance in your particular case, modify the resulting TVP definition (and the XML code) to contain the Exact Column domain you are expecting (to help the query optimiser). I.e. Don't use VARCHAR(MAX) but VARCHAR(50) if you are sure the single values are max 50 characters in length.